# Pull Image from local docker self signed registry

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, docker-registry

I have configured a 4 node k8s cluster with containerd. This cluster contains 2 master and 2 worker. I have also configured a local docker registry with self-signed certificate to pull images.
here is my deployment file-

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: gowebapp-mysql
  labels:
    app: gowebapp-mysql
    tier: backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: gowebapp-mysql
      tier: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: gowebapp-mysql
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: gowebapp-mysql
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: mypassword
        image: dhub.xxx.com.bd:443/gowebapp-mysql:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
```

when i am trying to apply this deployment it returns ImagePullBackOff -

```
samrat@k8smaster01:~/k8s/gowebapp/gowebapp-mysql$ kubectl get pods
NAME                              READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
gowebapp-mysql-78fc9df568-4z6p9   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          12s
```

In description it is showing  `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

I have placed self-signed certificate into all node's  `/etc/docker/certs.d/dhub.xxx.com.bd\:443/` location and central ca store `/etc/ssl/certs`.
I can manually pull image with `docker pull` and `ctr image pull`.

but can't pull by applying  yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

> As explained in the [doc](https://www.tutorialworks.com/kubernetes-imagepullbackoff/#in-kubernetes-the-kubelet-agent-on-each-node-pulls-the-image) written by Tom Donohue:
>
> The status ImagePullBackOff means that a Pod couldn’t start, because
> Kubernetes couldn’t pull a container image. The ‘BackOff’ part means
> that Kubernetes will keep trying to pull the image, with an increasing
> delay
>
> ImagePullBackOff  can be caused by typos, wrong tag names, missing
> registry secrets.
>
> So the ImagePullBackOff error is a sign that something is blocking
> Kubernetes from being able to pull the image you want onto a specific
> node.
>
> **To resolve this error try below troubleshooting**:
>
> Use `kubectl describe` to get the root cause.
>
> This will show you the full error log of the Pod, so you can see
> what’s causing the issue.
>
> If you’re pulling an image from a private registry, make sure that
> you’ve created a Secret containing the credentials you need to access.
> Also make sure that you’ve added the Secret in the appropriate
> namespace.
>
> You’ll also need to set the imagePullSecrets field on your Pod. This
> field tells Kubernetes which Secret it should use, when authenticating
> to the registry.

X509 errors: X509 errors usually indicate that you are attempting to use a self-signed certificate without configuring the Docker daemon correctly. See [run an insecure registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/).

Refer this [doc](https://itnext.io/error-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority-error-is-returned-f0e5d436f467) authored by Mykola Prokopenko for more information about ERROR: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority error is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the certificates in /etc/ssl/certs then run
sudo update-ca-certificates on all worker nodes
Also if your repository is private create a kubernetes secret of type docker registry in the same name space where the pod is being deployed

Answer (score -1):

I had the same scenario as you. What solved it is to restart containerd in all nodes.

```
sudo systemctl restart containerd
```

Comment: The problem is not the cert but what entity signed it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @user2363318 it's a self-signed certificate. He made it. He signed it. That's why he placed the cert in each of his worker node. He can do docker pull/push ctr image pull/push into his own local image registry. The problem is containerd needs to be restarted so k8s will "see" the self-signed cert.